# What is the difference between covariance and contra-variance in programming languages?

Tags: java, c#, programming-languages, covariance, contravariance

Can anyone explain the concept of covariance and contravariance in
programming language theory?

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance\_(computer\_science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science))

Comment: I smell a homework question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# : Is Variance (Covariance / Contravariance) another word for Polymorphism?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078423/c-sharp-is-variance-covariance-contravariance-another-word-for-polymorphis)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*Covariance* is pretty simple and best thought of from the perspective of some collection class `List`. We can *parameterize* the `List` class with some type parameter `T`. That is, our list contains elements of type `T` for some `T`. List would be covariant if

> S is a subtype of T iff List[S] is a subtype of List[T]

(Where I'm using the mathematical definition *iff* to mean *if and only if*.)

That is, a `List[Apple]` **is a** `List[Fruit]`. If there is some routine which accepts a `List[Fruit]` as a parameter, and I have a `List[Apple]`, then I can pass this in as a valid parameter.

```
def something(l: List[Fruit]) {
    l.add(new Pear())
}
```

If our collection class `List` is mutable, then covariance makes no sense because we might assume that our routine could add some other fruit (which was not an apple) as above. Hence we should only like *immutable* collection classes to be covariant!

Comment: Good definition, but it misses the fact that not only types can be treated as co/contravariant. For example, Java `List<T>` isn't either, but Java wildcards let you treat in either covariant or contravariant fashion at point of use (rather than declaration) - of course, restricting the set of operations on the type to those that are actually covariant and contravariant for it.

Comment: I believe that `List<? extends Fruit>` is a kind of *existential type*: i.e. `List[T] forSome T <: Fruit` - the *forSome T <: Fruit* is itself a type in this instance. Java is still not covariant in this type though. For example a method accepting a `List<? extends Fruit>` would not accept `List<? extends Fruit>`

Comment: OTOH, `S <= T iff List[T] <= List[S]` with respect to the `add` operation, since we can `add` things of type `S` to a `List[T]` if `S <= T`. So lists are contravariant with respect to the `add` operation.

Comment: I would have found it very useful if you had expanded your answer to demonstrate contravariance using fruit. I feel like after reading it I understand covariance but still don't understand contravariance.

Answer (score 21):

There is a distinction being made between ***covariance*** and ***contravariance***. 
Very roughly, an operation is covariant if it preserves the ordering of types, and contravariant if it **reverses** this order.

The ordering itself is meant to represent more general types as larger than more specific types. 
Here's one example of a situation where C# supports covariance. First, this is an array of objects:

```
var objects = new object[3];
objects[0] = new object();
objects[1] = "Just a string";
objects[2] = 10;
```

Of course it is possible to insert different values into the array because in the end they all derive from `System.Object` in .Net framework. In other words, `System.Object` is a very general or **large** type. Now here's a spot where covariance is supported:

***assigning a value of a smaller type to a variable of a larger type***

```
var strings = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
objects = strings;
```

The variable objects, which is of type `object[]`, can store a value that is in fact of type `string[]`.

Think about it — to a point, it's what you expect, but then again it isn't. After all, while `string` derives from `object`, `string[]` **DOES NOT** derive from `object[]`. The language support for covariance in this example makes the assignment possible anyway, which is something you'll find in many cases. *Variance* is a feature that makes the language work more intuitively.

The considerations around these topics are extremely complicated. For instance, based on the preceding code, here are two scenarios that will result in errors.

```
// Runtime exception here - the array is still of type string[],
// ints can't be inserted
objects[2]=10;

// Compiler error here - covariance support in this scenario only
// covers reference types, and int is a value type
var ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
objects = ints;
```

An example for the workings of contravariance is a bit more complicated. Imagine these
two classes:

```
public partial class Person: IPerson 
{
    public Person() 
    {
    }
}

public partial class Woman: Person
{
    public Woman()
    {
    }
}
```

`Woman` is derived from `Person`, obviously. Now consider you have these two functions:

```
static void WorkWithPerson(Person person)
{
}

static void WorkWithWoman(Woman woman)
{
}
```

One of the functions does something(it doesn't matter what) with a `Woman`, the other is more general and can work with any type derived from `Person`. On the `Woman` side of things, you now also have these:

```
delegate void AcceptWomanDelegate(Woman person);

static void DoWork(Woman woman, AcceptWomanDelegate acceptWoman)
{
    acceptWoman(woman);
}
```

`DoWork` is a function that can take a `Woman` and a reference to a function that also takes a `Woman`, and then it passes the instance of `Woman` to the delegate. Consider the *polymorphism* of the elements you have here. `Person` is *larger* than `Woman`, and `WorkWithPerson` is *larger* than `WorkWithWoman`.
`WorkWithPerson` is also considered *larger* than `AcceptWomanDelegate` for the purpose of variance.

Finally, you have these three lines of code:

```
var woman = new Woman();
DoWork(woman, WorkWithWoman);
DoWork(woman, WorkWithPerson);
```

A `Woman` instance is created. Then DoWork is called, passing in the `Woman` instance as well as a reference to the `WorkWithWoman` method. The latter is obviously compatible with the delegate type `AcceptWomanDelegate` — one parameter of type `Woman`, no return type.
The third line is a bit odd, though. The method `WorkWithPerson` takes a `Person` as parameter, not a `Woman`, as required by `AcceptWomanDelegate`. Nevertheless, `WorkWithPerson` is compatible with the delegate type. ***Contravariance*** makes it possible, so in the case of delegates the larger type `WorkWithPerson` can be stored in a variable of the smaller type `AcceptWomanDelegate`. Once more it's the intuitive thing: ***if `WorkWithPerson` can work with any `Person`, passing in a `Woman` can't be wrong***, right?

By now, you may be wondering how all this relates to generics. The answer is that variance can be applied to generics as well. The preceding example used `object` and `string` arrays. Here the code uses generic lists instead of the arrays:

```
var objectList = new List<object>();
var stringList = new List<string>();
objectList = stringList;
```

If you try this out, you will find that this is not a supported scenario in C#. In C# version 4.0 as well as .Net framework 4.0, variance support in generics has been cleaned up, and it is now possible to use the new keywords ***in*** and ***out*** with generic type parameters. They can define and restrict the direction of data flow for a particular type parameter, allowing variance to work. But in the case of `List<T>`, the data of type `T` flows in both directions — there are methods on the type `List<T>` that return `T` values, and others that receive such values.

The point of these directional restrictions is **to allow variance where it makes sense**, but to **prevent problems** like the runtime error mentioned in one of the previous array examples. When type parameters are correctly decorated with *in* or *out*, the compiler can check, and allow or disallow, its variance at ***compile time***. Microsoft has gone to the effort of adding these keywords to many standard interfaces in .Net framework, like `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T>: IEnumerable
{
    // ...
}
```

For this interface, the data flow of type `T` objects is clear: ***they can only ever be retrieved from methods supported by this interface, not passed into them***. As a result, it is possible to construct an example similar to the `List<T>` attempt described previously, but using `IEnumerable<T>` :

```
IEnumerable<object> objectSequence = new List<object>();
IEnumerable<string> stringSequence = new List<string>();
objectSequence = stringSequence;
```

This code is acceptable to the C# compiler since version 4.0 because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant due to the *out* specifier on the type parameter `T`.

When working with generic types, it is important to be aware of variance and the way the compiler is applying various kinds of trickery in order to make your code work the way you expect it to.

There's more to know about variance than is covered in this chapter, but this shall suffice to make all further code understandable.

Ref:

- [`PROFESSIONAL Functional Programming in C#`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470744588)

Answer (score 2):

**Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Invariance**

**Type(T)**

`composite data type` - is a type which is built out of another type. For example it can be generic, container(collection), optional[<sup>[example]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61232621/4770877)

`method's type` - method's `parameter type`(pre-condition) and `return type`(post-condition)[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64789005/4770877)

**Variance**

`Variance` - is about assignment compatibility. It is an ability to use a `derived type` **instead of** `original type`. It is **not** `parent-child` relationship

```
X(T) - `composite data type` or `method type` X, with type T
```

`Covariance`(**same** subtyping direction) you are able to assign **more** `derived type` than `original type`(strives for -> X(C))

`X(T) covariant` or `X(T1) is covariant to X(T2)` when relation T1 to T2 is the same as X(T1) to X(T2)

`Contravariance`(**opposite** subtyping direction) you are able to assign **less** `derived type` then `original type`(strives for -> X(A))

`X(T) contravariant` or `X(T1) is contravariant to X(T2)` when relation T1 to T2 is the same as X(T2) to X(T1)

`Invariance` neither `Covariance` not `Contravariance`. There is exists also [<sup>[Class Invariant]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64788342/4770877)

**Examples**

Class directions, pseudocode

```
//C -> B -> A

class A {}
class B: A {}
class C: B {}
```

Reference type Array in Java is covariant

```
A[] aArray = new A[2];
B[] bArray = new B[2];

//A - original type, B - more derived type
//B[] is covariant to A[]
aArray = bArray;
```

```
class Generic<T> { }

//A - original type, B - more derived type
//Generic<B> is covariant to Generic<A>
//assign more derived type(B) than original type(A)
Generic<? extends A> ref = new Generic<B>(); //covariant

//B - original type, A - less derived type
//Generic<B> is contravariant to Generic<A>
//assign less derived type(A) then original type(B)
Generic<? super B> ref = new Generic<A>(); //contravariant

<sub_type> covariant/contravariant to <super_type>
```

Swift

- Array
- Generic
- Closure

Swift Array is covariance

```
let array:[B] = [C()]
```

Swift Generic is Invariance

```
class Wrapper<T> {
    let value: T
    
    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

```
let generic1: Wrapper<A> = Wrapper<B>(value: B()) //ERROR: Cannot assign value of type 'Wrapper<B>' to type 'Wrapper<A>'
let generic2: Wrapper<B> = Wrapper<A>(value: A()) //ERROR: Cannot assign value of type 'Wrapper<A>' to type 'Wrapper<B>'
```

**Swift closure**

closure’s return type is covariance
closure’s argument type is contravariance

```
var foo1: (A) -> C = { _ in return C() }
let foo2: (B) -> B = foo1

covariance
() -> B = () -> C

contravariance 
(A) -> Void = (B) -> Void
```

[[Liskov principle]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64789005/4770877)

[[Java generics]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62171149/4770877)

Answer (score 0):

Both C# and the CLR allow for covariance and contra-variance of reference types when
binding a method to a delegate. Covariance means that a method can return a type that is
derived from the delegate’s return type. Contra-variance means that a method can take a
parameter that is a base of the delegate’s parameter type. For example, given a delegate
defined like this:

```
delegate Object MyCallback(FileStream s);
```

It is possible to construct an instance of this delegate type bound to a method that is prototyped

Like this:

```
String SomeMethod(Stream s);
```

Here, SomeMethod’s return type (String) is a type that is derived from the delegate’s return type (Object); this covariance is allowed. SomeMethod’s parameter type (Stream) is a type that is a base class of the delegate’s parameter type (FileStream); this contra-variance is allowed.

Note that covariance and contra-variance are supported only for reference types, not for value types or for void. So, for example, I cannot bind the following method to the MyCallback delegate:

```
Int32 SomeOtherMethod(Stream s);
```

Even though SomeOtherMethod’s return type (Int32) is derived from MyCallback’s return
type (Object), this form of covariance is not allowed because Int32 is a value type.

Obviously, the reason why value types and void cannot be used for covariance and
contra-variance is because the memory structure for these things varies, whereas the
memory structure for reference types is always a pointer. Fortunately, the C# compiler will
produce an error if you attempt to do something that is not supported.