# How do I pass an ArrayList to method that takes a collection as an input

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, interface-implementation

I want to pass some `ArrayList<Integer>` X into method `a(Collection<Integer> someCol)` that takes `Collection<Integer>` as an input.

How can I do this? I thought an ArrayList was a Collection and thus I should be able to "just do it" but it seems that Collection is an interface and ArrayList implements this interface. Is there something I can do to make this work ... if you understand the theory that would also help me and possibly lots of other people.

Thanks

Comment: DId you really try with it? Is there any problem or compiler error or run time error? Because, I suppose that they should work perfectly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just do it.

Seriously, a class will implicitly cast to an interface for which it implements.

**Edit**
In case you needed an example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sandbox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
        Collections.addAll(list, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        printAll(list);
    }

    private static void printAll(Collection<Integer> collection) {
        for (Integer num : collection)
            System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[`class ArrayList<E> implements List<E>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [`interface List<E> extends Collection<E>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), so an `ArrayList<Integer>` is-a `Collection<Integer>`.

This is what is called "subtyping".

Note, however, that even though [`Integer extends Number`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), a `List<Integer>` is-not-a `List<Number>`. It is, however, a `List<? extends Number>`. That is, generics in Java is invariant; it's not covariant.

Arrays on the other hand, are covariant. An `Integer[]` is-a `Number[]`.

#### References

- [Wikipedia: Subtype polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism)
- [JLS 4.10 Subtyping](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10)

  - [JLS 4.10.2 Subtyping among Class and Interface Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10.2)
  - [JLS 4.10.3 Subtyping among Array Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10.3)
- [Java Tutorials/Generics/Subtyping](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html)

#### Related questions

- [What is the difference between `<E extends Number>` and `<Number>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770264/what-is-the-difference-between-e-extends-number-and-number/)
- [Covariance and contravariance in programming languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163465/covariance-and-contravariance-in-programming-languages)
- [What is the purpose of interfaces? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667139/what-is-the-purpose-of-interfaces-closed)

  - [How will I know when to create an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444245/)
- [Why doesn’t Java Map extends Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651819/why-doesnt-java-map-extends-collection)

Comment: This is a pretty awesome answer, thanks for taking the time to write it up and link to everything.