# Covariance and Contravariance

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Covariance and contravariance real world example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example)
>   [still confused about covariance and contravariance & in/out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631/still-confused-about-covariance-and-contravariance-in-out)

Can you give me a description or example of both covariance and contravaiance, and why they now decided to add it to .NET 4?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-4-0

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163465/covariance-and-contravariance-in-programming-languages and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631/still-confused-about-covariance-and-contravariance-in-out ...hell ..just enter both terms in search box...easier that way

Comment: Ok, cool this should give me something to read for a bit. I am trying to get a high-level summary, and also how I can implement co/contravariance in my own app.

Comment: You might also want to read the twenty or so articles I've written on the subject of how we designed and implemented variance. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If B inherits from A, ie is a subtype of A, then C function is covariant if C(B) is a subtype of C(A), contravariant if C(A) is a subtype of C(B).

**The question is wether or not you want consumers to deal with supertypes or subtypes.**

A common example is a class library dealing in fruit classes.

It is OK for me to give you an apple where you expect a fruit.
It is not OK for me to give you just any fruit where you expect an apple.

If you were making a fruit library. You should be expecting instances fruit from me and I should be expecting instances of fruit from you. Neither of us should have expectations about a subtype that could be false.

Therefore, the answer to the question above depends on wether you're getting or sending. Wether the parameter is read or write.
A fruit list should be *accepting* bananas or apples, but only *send* "fruits"

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no answer given I just summarize the comments

stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/ – MainMa

stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/
stackoverflow.com/questions/1163465/
stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631/  – In Sane 56 mins ago