# Why A->B doesn't make List<A>->List<B>? Wouldn't that remove need for wildcards?

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics, covariance

*Disclaimer: I'm not a professional developer, and I'm not intending to become one. Reading book about Java, as I wanted to try Android programming, no previous Java experience whatsoever.*

I'm reading [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349806) - and I rather like it. I've read part of chapter about generic classes, got to the point where they mention wildcards, and got confused.

If B extends A:

1. `List<B>` **is not** a subtype of `List<A>` (as I understand it they're exactly the same)
2. `List<? extends B>` is a subtype of `List<? extends A>`

The latter allows for writing functions that accept arguments that are of generic type - for example `List<? extends A>`. Such function would accept an argument of either `List<B>` or `List<A>`.

Now, for my question:

Wouldn't it be simpler to implement generics in a manner similar to C++ (in a "template" flavour)? This would make `List<B>` and `List<A>` two separate types, that would be related in expected way. This would also allow to simply state in a function that you expect an argument to be of type `List<A>`, which would allow `List<B>` to fit there just fine.

I'm guessing there was more than *"we hate C++, let's make things different"* behind this :) It's also quite possible that I don't know something yet, that makes wildcards a fantastic and useful tool. What's your take on this?

**Edit:** if you're mentioning `List<X>` in your answer, remember to use backticks, to avoid `<X>` being interpreted as HTML tag.

Comment: Ref Covariance and contravariance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1163465/203968

Comment: `std::list<B>` does not "fit there just fine" in place of `std::list<A>` in C++. The types are unrelated. The mechanism is different from Java but rationale is the same - collection types would grossly violate the Liskov Substitution Principle if they were covariant.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with the C++ part. As @Steve says, the types would be *completely* unrelated in C++, and one can't be substituted for the other.

Answer (score 5):

There's a simple reason.

Suppose you have a variable of type `List<A>`. Suppose `List<B>` was indeed a subtype of `List<A>`.

That means that when this would be legal:

```
List<A> a_list;
a_list = new List<B>(); //allowed when List<B> is subtype of list<A>
a_list.add(new A()); // WOAH!
```

Where I say WOAH, the following happens: You add an item of type A to a_list. Since a_list was declared as `List<A>`, this should be legal. But wait: a_list is pointing to something of type `List<B>`.

So now we add something of type A to a list that should store only items of type B, and this is clearly not what we want, since A is not a subclass of B!

Comment: And yet when you try to do this with arrays it compiles, then throws at runtime when you hit the WOAH!  Phooey on covariant arrays.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Arrays at least throw when you try to add something of the wrong type to them... generic constructs like a `List` won't throw until whenever you try to read something from them and cast it to something that it isn't.

Comment: @Colin: That's the trouble with generics-by-type-erasure.  Why the heck did they extend the JVM bytecode for assertions but not for generics?

Answer (score 1):

If List<B> was a subtype of List<A> the following code would be legal, as java does remove most of the Generic magic at compile time. (If that was a good decision or not is a different topic).

```
public void addNewAToList(List<A> list) {
    list.add(new A());
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<B> listB = new LinkedList<B>();
    addNewAToList(listB);       // <--- compiler error
    for (B b : listB) {         // <--- otherwise: there is an A in the list.
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: First sentence of your answer probably have `List<X>` - please put those into backticks, as SO thinks `<X>` are HTML tags :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you have `class C extends A` and are given a `List<A>`, you can put a `C` in because a `C` is an `A`. But if Java allowed you to just give the method a `List<B>`, then you're putting a `C` in a list of `B`s. And a `C` is not a `B`, so there'll be an error down the line. Java's wildcard solution doesn't let you add anything but `null` to a `List<? extends A>`, saving you from this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [Comeau c++ online compiler](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) fails on this:

```
template<typename T> class List {
};

class A {
};

class B: public A {
};

void function(List<A> listA) {
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    List<A> a;
    List<B> b;

    function(a);
    function(b);
}
```

giving this error:

```
"ComeauTest.c", line 18: error: no suitable user-defined conversion from "List<B>" to
          "List<A>" exists
  function(b);
```

So C++ and Java are similar when dealing with these kinds of types.

Answer (score 0):

Static typing dictates that a subtype must support all operations of its supertype.

`List<Fruit>` supports inserting `Fruit` objects.

`List<Banana>` does not -- you cannot insert arbitrary fruits into a `List<Banana>`, only bananas.

Hence, `List<Banana>` is not a subtype of `List<Fruit>`.