# What does the method below mean in terms of generics?

Tags: java

I would like to know what does the declaration of the following method mean:

```
<T> T method(List<? extends T>) {...}
```

This method would be the same if `List<? extends T>` becomes `List<T>` ? If not, why?

Comment: `List<? extends T>` means any `List` holding types of sub-classes of `T`. Where `List<T>` is self-explanatory.

Comment: I recommend reading https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm really confused because I didn't find a point to use List<? extends T> over List<T> on this particular case ( ignore any kind of implementation ).

Comment: Pedro Henrique Silva Almeida try reading my answer and see if it helps you explain the concept of [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163465/covariance-and-contravariance-in-programming-languages)

Answer (score 1):

`<T> T method(List<? extends T>) {...}` means this method can accept an `Object` that meets this criteria: `List<? extends T>` where `?` represents a sub-class that is-A `T`.

**Note:** `List<T>` or `List<? extends T>` or `List<? super E>` or `List<Integer>` or `List<Car>` are all **individual** objects. (Yes, `List` is a container (data structure) that further holds 1-to-many objects of its generic type i.e. `T, E, Integer, Car` etc above)

#### Ceremonial example:

Say you have a class structure as:

```
class Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
```

then you have a method accepting container (data structure) like

```
public void updatePets (List<Animal> myPetsList) {}
```

When you try to pass `List<Dog>`, then you will get a compile error. Not allowed.
Because **object ->** `List<Dog>` is not same as **object ->** `List<Animal>`. However, **object ->** `List<Dog>` can be same as **object ->** `List<? extends Animal>`. Do not confuse `Animal` and `List<Animal>` as same objects. These are two separate type of objects; one is user defined while other is defined by Java lang `List` specifying a generic object type it can hold.

So your fixed method signature will become:

```
public void updatePets (List<? extends Animal> myPetsList) {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understood what is the real meaning. I really appreciate it.