# what is the definition of an Invariant?

Tags: algorithm, terminology, definition

I'm going through past papers and i just wanted to double check the definition of the following.

"Something that doesn't change when we move from state to state is referred to as ___________?"

Am i correct in saying that this would be defined as an Invariant?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an invariant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112064/what-is-an-invariant)

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my understanding of what an invariant is. How would you define the statement in original post?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_%28computer_science%29), an invariant is

> a condition that can be relied upon to be true during execution of a
>   program, or during some portion of it.

which basically means that "invariant" would be a correct solution to the question in the original post.